# Error: Mapping should be created with `aes()` or `aes_()`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to run the code below but encounter an error.

```
ggplot(Weekdag.en.uren, aes(x = Uur, y = count, group = 1)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~Weekdag)
```

Comment: Please provide your data in `dput(Weekdag.en.uren)` format. visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Inside `aes` the right hand side of equalities should be variables, but it is not the case of `group = 1`. I would say this is the reason of the error. So you may want to do `ggplot(Weekdag.en.uren, aes(x = Uur, y = count), group = 1)` instead.